# How to install ansible on a RHEL machine which doesn't have access to Internet

Tags: ansible, rhel

How to install ansible on a RHEL 6.8 machine which doesn't have access to Internet?

Comment: Hi Arun, welcome to SO. Your question is at risk of closure because of two things: the first is that those style of questions should go to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) since it is not related to programming. The second is that you have not said any steps that you have already tried; reading the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will go a long way toward making your stay here on SO much more productive.

Comment: I'd disagree, as ansible is a well-established topic for SO, and ansible bootstrap is a Big Topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to use `raw`: module. Copy rpm (scp) to server, and run rpm -i.

Raw module does not use a usual ansible workflow and do things 'directly'. Here my code to install python if it's not present on server, I think you can adopt it for rpm for ansible too.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   - name: Remember sever key and install python
     raw: test -x /usr/bin/python || sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install python
     changed_when: True
```